# How to change window Title bar Color in WinUI 3

Tags: winui-3, titlebar, windows-app-sdk, custom-titlebar

Been looking into docs, web and the gallery app. The code provided in the UI Gallery app is not working.

[Title bar Default Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iclzj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk) here.

For Windows 11:

**MainWindow.cs**

```cs
private bool SetTitleBarColors()
{
    // Check to see if customization is supported.
    // The method returns true on Windows 10 since Windows App SDK 1.2, and on all versions of
    // Windows App SDK on Windows 11.
    if (AppWindowTitleBar.IsCustomizationSupported())
    {
        if (m_AppWindow is null)
        {
            m_AppWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
        }
        var titleBar = m_AppWindow.TitleBar;

        // Set active window colors
        // Note: No effect when app is running on Windows 10 since color customization is not
        // supported.
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.SeaGreen;
        titleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = Colors.Gainsboro;
        titleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkSeaGreen;
        titleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = Colors.Gray;
        titleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Colors.LightGreen;

        // Set inactive window colors
        // Note: No effect when app is running on Windows 10 since color customization is not
        // supported.
        titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Colors.Gainsboro;
        titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.SeaGreen;
        titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Colors.Gainsboro;
        titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.SeaGreen;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For Windows 10, you need to take a different approach:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TitleBarIconExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TitleBarIconExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="28,*">
        <!--  Title bar  -->
        <Grid
            x:Name="AppTitleBar"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Background="LightGreen">
            <Image
                Width="16"
                Height="16"
                Margin="8,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Source="Assets/WindowIcon.png" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="AppTitleTextBlock"
                Margin="28,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="App title"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
        </Grid>

        <!--  Contents  -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <!--  Contents here.  -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
        SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
    }
}
```

Let me also mention that the **CommunityToolkit Labs** is working on [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Labs-Windows/discussions/454).

Comment: The solution for windows 10 does not work when using MAUI. The method `SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);` expects an object from WinUI, but MAUI have a different set of visual components. Is there a way to do this in MAUI too? Thanks for a great answer anyway!