# Customize the Windows 10 title bar using .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, windows-10, maui

I have found this excellent resource for how to modify the title bar in Windows 10 and 11 with WinUI:

[How to change window Title bar Color in WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76663642/how-to-change-window-title-bar-color-in-winui-3)

Unfortunately, when using MAUI I can't apply the method described for Windows 10. The method `SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);` expects an `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UIElement` object from the WinUI framework, but since I'm using MAUI I rely on a different set of visual components.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar) has no mentions of MAUI. So how do I gain full access to customize the Windows 10 title bar when using .NET MAUI?

**EDIT:** I want to include interactive components in the title bar.

Comment: _"So how do I gain full access to customize the Windows 10 title bar when using .NET MAUI?"_- I don't think you're meant to, seeming as the whole point of MAUI is having a cross-platform RAD-ish UI platform and _not_ about getting a high-level of control over a single specific platform - otherwise for that you should use WinUI (though I'm sure MAUI has enough escape-hatches and extensibility points).

Comment: Yeah that's a good point @Dai, but that would still make me sad.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar#colors

> Color customization is ignored when the app runs on Windows 10.

So you may try another solution to change the titlebar's background color. You can open the `App.xaml` in the **Platforms\Windows** folder, add following code in the maui:MauiWinUIApplication tag, the title bar's background color can be changed by Background in Border control and also you can customize the title by TextBlock:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MauiAppTitleBarTemplate">

            <Grid >

                <Border

                  Canvas.ZIndex="1"

                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"

                  Background="Azure"

                  Margin="0,0,0,0">

                    <TextBlock

                      Foreground="Red"

                      VerticalAlignment="Center"

                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"

                      Text="Custom your  application title"

                      FontWeight="Bold"/>

                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! That works! It would be awesome if you could also include an example of how to add interactive components, such as a clickable button. Because I can't get that to work. If I add a button like: `<Button x:Name="NavBtn" Click="OnNavBtnClicked" Content="Great stuff" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>` I get the cheerful message that "(WMC1005) Events cannot be set in the Application class XAML file".

Comment: I'll see if we can add an interactive button into it.

Comment: @stack-delay After researching, I think you can't directly add `Click="OnNavBtnClicked"` which will cause error. There's a different way to customize the title bar via xaml style, you can refer to it:https://github.com/dorisoy/Dorisoy.Rigger/blob/main/DoryRiggerMaui/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml

Comment: Thanks for the effort @alexandar-may-msft !! When I have had the time to take a proper look at this I will add my final solution. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Feel free to post your solution if you got any progress.